# "Open Live Beans Graph" is disabled

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a Spring MVC project inside of Spring Tools Suite that uses Java based Spring configuration and Gradle.
 - I've added the Spring Project Nature. 
 - I'm not using @ComponentScan, I define all beans explicitly. 
 - I have "Auto detection for annotated Java Spring configuration files" turned on.

Why is "Open Live Beans Graph" disabled (greyed out) in my Project/Spring Tools menu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The live beans graph is showing the beans that are being created in the running application, so you need to run the app (in your case I guess you run that in tc Server), and open the live beans graph view for that application. You can do that from the tc Server editor, there is a section for live bean graphs being available (and you can enable the feature in general).

If you do not run the app in tc Server, you have to set a property in order to enable this feature in your running application and connect to that application from the live beans graph view manually.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the post. I'm not using tc Server, I'm running the app using the Gradle tomcatRunWar tasks. This kicks off the app. What confuses me is that this feature was previously working 'out of the box'. 

I've looked for a property to set but can't find anything that points in the right direction.

Comment: "What confuses me is that this feature was previously working 'out of the box'" When did it break? Maybe it is a bug/regression and you should consider filing a bug report with enough details so we can reproduce and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC may not be enough to get it to work.

https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v310/NewAndNoteworthy.html says:

> To allow proper communication, servers must be configured to enable
>   JMX and must also be given the VM argument
>   '-Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in order for the Spring Framework
>   to produce the data required to build up the graph.

I think the easiest is to get it to run in Spring Boot.

https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.3/#jmx-bean-management